# failed 500 internal server error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I m getting Internal server error (500) making an AJAX request. I m not sure why the request is failing. Need help in this. Here is my code.

```
$('#LanguageId').on('change', function(){
    var setValue =JSON.stringify( $('#LanguageId').val());
    console.log(typeof(setValue));
    $.ajax({
        url: '/RootObjects/SaveLanguage',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:setValue ,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
})
```

and the controller's action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveLanguage(string LanguageId)
    {
        GlobalVariables.LangId = LanguageId.ToString();
        return View("Index");
    }
```

can't understand what is wrong

Comment: Your method returns html (a view), not json, so it needs to be `dataType: 'json',` and it needs to be `data: JSON.stringify({ LanguageId: setValue })`

Comment: Or better just `data: { LanguageId: setValue }` and delete the `contentType` option

Comment: thank you,,,i change as you say,but still the same error

Comment: What exactly does the 500 error say?

Comment: now when i change as you say, it says the resource can not be found, before that failed with 500 error but opened action link when click on it

Comment: now ,,,POST http://localhost:50615/RootObjects/SaveLanguage 500 (Internal Server Error)----jquery-1.10.2.js:8720

Comment: Then it means that your controller code is also throwing an exception. Use your browser tools (the Network tab) to inspect the response. It will give the full details of the error

Comment: One of the problems is that you are doing JSON.stringify on a string which isn't needed as its already a string. Just do data: { LanguageId: $('#LanguageId').val() } in the ajax call and it should match your controllers routing.

Comment: i just clear Json.stringify(), nothing changes , don't understand where is the problem, maybe the problem is argument type or something like that?

Comment: @ZhanVardanyan, If you use `data: { LanguageId: $('#LanguageId').val() }` (which you should) you also need to remove `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',`

Comment: yes i did it, but nothing changes

Comment: @ZhanVardanyan, Then what does the Network tab tell you. (and not related but why in the world are you using `LanguageId.ToString();` - its already a `string`)

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax request like this:-

```
$('#LanguageId').on('change', function(){

    var setValue =$('#LanguageId').val();
    console.log(typeof(setValue));
    $.ajax({

        url: '/RootObjects/SaveLanguage',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{'LanguageId':setValue} ,
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
})
```

Comment: with console.log(setValue) i get the value of setValue,but after that get 500 internal server error